# Set the initial capacity of ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists. I would like to set the initial capacity of the inner ArrayLists as well as the outer ArrayList, though not necessarily to the same size. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: So every time you create the arraylist, set its initial capacity in the constructor.. What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get confuse.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> outerlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(outCapacity);
```

And

```
ArrayList<String> innerList= new ArrayList<String>(InnCapacity);

// adding some elements to innerlist as well.
```

Now

```
outerList.add(innerList);
```

So you just added capacity for outerlist and innerlist as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works when the inner class is an ArrayList instead of a List.

Answer (score 3):

The only place where you can set the initial capacity of an `ArrayList` is when creating the specific instance using [`ArrayList(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). There's no direct method to set the initial capacity of the internal `ArrayList`s of a collection to a specific size at once.

Comment: Well you could use Reflection to set the initial capacity of *all* `ArrayList`s to something ^_^